# angular-translate module 'pascalprecht.translate' not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

I'm trying to add *angular-translate* to my angular app. I followed this simple quick start: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide, but my app won't bootstrap, giving me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module pascalprecht.translate due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'pascalprecht.translate' is not available!
>   You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
>   registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the
>   second argument.

My *index.html* file is properly including *angular-translate* like so:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
```

Any clue why this could be happening?. I'd really appreciate the help.

**UPDATE**

Here's part of my *app.js* to clarify things a bit:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',

  // 3rd party modules.
  'ui.router',
  'restangular',
  'angular.filter',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'pascalprecht.translate',


  // Custom modules.
  'myApp.config'
])
.
.
.
```

Comment: As it says, `If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.` -- so, did you? I.e. could you show a bit more of your code, if you did specify dependencies correctly.

Comment: yep I did specify the 'pascalprecht.translate' dependency. I'm updating the question to show a bit of my *app.js*

Comment: Ok, things do look to be ok.. did you already check with your browser's network monitor, that the `angular-translate.js` file is indeed loading correctly?

Comment: Yes. The browser is indeed loading the file correctly. angular-translate.js is in the loaded resources.

Comment: Ok, seems quite weird. Was everything working until you introduced angular-translate? What if you now remove angular-translate dependency and the angular-translate.js from loading?

Comment: if you comment out the translate module as a dependency, do you still get the error? Maybe the translate module is working okay, but something else isn't.

Comment: I realized there was a dependency that was throwing an error with require.js. I wasn't using that dependency so I removed it, then angular-translate started working with no problem. It was somehow conflicting with that error. Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was failing because of another dependency throwing an error, specifically *jquery.easy-pie-chart*. I wasn't using that dependency at all so I removed it and *angular-translate* started working without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same problem, resolved it by adding below entries. Also remeber to put these .js files in correct order too.

```
files : [
         '../js/libs/angular.js',    
          '../libs/angular-route.js', 
          '../angular-translate.min.js',
          '../libs/angular-translate-loader-url.js',
```

Hope, this helps.

Regards,
Aditi.

Answer (score 1):

I had other modules depending on the translation module, so I was able to fix this error by loading it right after loading angular itself.